# incremental UI updates from multiple promises

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have an AngularJS service that's used to retrieve individual contacts (`/contacts/:id`) based on an index (`/contacts`):

```
app.service("CollectionService", function($http, $q) {
    this.fetch = function(collectionURL) {
        return $http.get(collectionURL).then(function(response) {
            var urls = response.data;
            var entities = urls.map(function(url) {
                return $http.get(url);
            });
            return $q.all(entities);
        }).then(function(responses) {
            return responses.map(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        });
    };
});

// used within the controller:
CollectionService.fetch("/contacts").then(function(contacts) {
    $scope.contacts = contacts;
});
```

The results are displayed in a simple list (`<li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">{{ contact }}</li>`).

However, due to the use of `$q.all`, that list is not updated until the last (slowest) response has been received. How would one switch from this bulk update to incremental updates as individual contacts are received?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use your own promise to return and then hook into a notification of the promise to give you an update on the overall loading progress, and still use `$q.all` to determine when this has finished. It is basically what you have now with slightly different way of handling and using a custom promise.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U4XPU/1/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-app="stackExample">
    <div class="loading" ng-show="loading">Loading</div>
    <div class="contacts" ng-controller="ContactController">
        <div class="contact" ng-repeat="contact in contacts">    {{contact.name}} - {{contact.dob}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
.controller("ContactController", ["$scope", "CollectionService", function (scope, service) {
    scope.contacts = [];
    scope.loading = true;

    service.fetch("/contacts")
        .then(
    // All complete handler
    function () {
        console.log("Loaded all contacts");
        scope.loading = false;
    },
    // Error handler
    function () {
        scope.error = "Ruh roh";
        scope.loading = false;
    },
    // Incremental handler with .notify
    function (newContacts) {
        console.log("New contacts found");
        scope.contacts = scope.contacts.concat(newContacts);
    });
}])
```

Service

```
.service("CollectionService", ["$q", "$http", function (q, http) {

    this.fetch = function (collectionUrl) {

        var deferred = q.defer();

        http.get(collectionUrl)
        .then(function (response) {

            // Still map all your responses to an array of requests
            var allRequests = response.data.map(function (url) {
                return http.get(url)
                    .then(function (innerResponse) {
                        deferred.notify(innerResponse.data);
                    });
            });

            // I haven't here, but you could still pass all of your data to resolve().
            q.all(allRequests).then(function () {
                deferred.resolve();
            });

        });

        return deferred.promise;

    }

}]);
```

You can also handle the errors as you see fit and `.reject()` the promise:

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q)

Comment: It seems like `notify` is exactly what I was looking for - not sure how I'd missed that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You could just pass the contacts list into fetch() and have it popupate the list.

```
app.service("CollectionService", function($http, $q) {
    this.fetch = function(collectionURL, resultList) {
        $http.get(collectionURL).then(function(response) {
            var urls = response.data;
            urls.forEach(function(url) {
                $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
                    resultList.push(response.data);
                });
            });
        };
    };
});

// used within the controller:
$scope.contacts = [];
CollectionService.fetch("/contacts", $scope.contacts);
```

Comment: I very much wanted to avoid awareness of the eventual data structure within the service. Also, there'd be no indication whether all items have been retrieved, not to mention error handling.

Comment: If you need a notification at the end you could always add back the $q.all(). This would also let the user of this function convert the data into any data structure they want after all urls have been retrieved. I also don't think there is anything wrong with your callback solution. As this (http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/) article states: "Promises allow developers to easily attach **1x-only** notifications of response to any asynchronous request/action.". So I don't think there is any way to get multiple notifications without using my solution or callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a workaround, permitting an `onResponse` callback which is invoked for each response individually:

```
var entities = urls.map(function(url) {
    var request = $http.get(url);
    if(onResponse) {
        request.then(function(response) {
            onResponse(response.data);
        });
    }
    return response; // this still allows for `$q.all` to handle completion
});
```

However, I'm not keen on the API mixing callbacks and promises - so I remain curious whether there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could work if you just return an empty list as a result and let the service add entries on every succceded request:

```
app.service("CollectionService", function($http, $q) {
    this.fetch = function(collectionURL) {
        var list = [];
        $http.get(collectionURL).then(function(response) {
            var urls = response.data;
            urls.forEach(function(url) {
                $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
                    list.push(response.data);
                });
            });
        };
        return list;
    };
});

$scope.contacts = CollectionService.fetch("/contacts");
```

Comment: I'd considered that, but that seemed even more of a workaround than my callback-based one. (For one thing, there'd be no indication whether all items have been retrieved, not to mention error handling.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, you need a solution which should

- Start showing contacts before all contacts are loaded
- Avoid callbacks
- Know when all contacts loaded
- Make sure only service knows about data structure
- Allow handling errors in controller

```
app.service("CollectionService", function($http, $q) {
    this.fetch = function(collectionURL) {
        return $http.get(collectionURL).then(function(response) {
            var urls = response.data;
            var contactPromises = urls.map(function(url) {
                return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
                    return $q.when(response.data);
                });
            });
            return $q.when(contactPromises);
        });
    };
});

// used within the controller:
$scope.contacts = [];
var addContact = function(contact) { $scope.contacts.push(contact); }; 

CollectionService.fetch("/contacts").then(function(contactPromises) {
    contactPromises.forEach(function(contactPromise){
        contactPromise.then(addContact);
    });
    return $q.all(contactPromise);        
}).then(function(){
   alert('All contacts loaded!');
}, function(){
   alert('Error!!');
});
```